# Ajax request does not send blob data

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to send data using an Ajax request to PHP.

I have the following data in my formData variable:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('fname', inputFname.value);
formData.append('lname', inputLname.value);
formData.append('email', inputEmail.value);
formData.append('data', newBlob);
```

Printing the form entries gives me this:
[image]
I do the request like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'post.php',
    data: formData,
    crossDomain: true,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log("success!")
        },    
    error: function() {
        console.log("error!")
    }
})
```

In post.php I print the recieved data:

```
print_r("First name: " . $_POST["fname"] . PHP_EOL);
print_r("Last name: " . $_POST["lname"] . PHP_EOL);
print_r("Email: " . $_POST["email"] . PHP_EOL); 
print_r("Data: " . $_POST["data"] . PHP_EOL);
```

For some reason it does not receive the 'data' entry in the $_POST variable. I get the following notice: "Notice: Undefined index: data"

Why does that happen? Could I somehow send the blob information?

As requested, the whole code. (inputFname, inputLname and inputEmail are not null. The code is situated inside a button onclick event method.

```
let evtTgt = e.target;
const container = evtTgt.parentNode;
const audioElement = container.getElementsByTagName("audio")[0];
const audioURL = audioElement.src;
let newBlob = await fetch(audioURL).then(result => result.blob());

var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('fname', inputFname.value);
formData.append('lname', inputLname.value);
formData.append('email', inputEmail.value);
formData.append('data', newBlob);

for (var key of formData.entries()) {
    console.log(key[1]);
}

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'post.php',
    data: formData,
    crossDomain: true,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log("success!")
        },    
    error: function() {
        console.log("error!")
    }
})
```

Comment: where and how do you create `newBlob`? What does the console reveal about your request?

Comment: The variable `newBlob` is created in this line:
`let newBlob = await fetch(audioURL).then(result => result.blob());`
Basically this is an audio/ogg file.
The console says that the request succeeded.

Comment: but then how does that tie in with the jQuery ajax function? And why mix `fetch` with jQuery ajax?

Comment: From what I understand, what I did (and what I was trying to do) was to fetch the blob from an url and then send it in a form to post.php where it is processed. 

The blob is fetched from the url.
The data is stored in formData.
All data in formData is sent to post.php excepting the blob data. Also, the line which initialises the blob is right above the initialisation of the formData variable in the same method.

Comment: could you show the complete javascript code - where the `fetch` routine and then the `$.ajax` routine combine

Comment: I edited the post with the new code.

Comment: As I mentioned before - why mix jQuery with fetch? That said, you should use the callback from the `fetch` call to fire the ajax request.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226750/discussion-between-olddew-and-professor-abronsius).

Answer (score 0):

All this time I was looking for the blob contents inside the $_POST variable. I should have looked in the $_FILES variable instead!

I managed to get the file contents by calling this inside the php script:

```
$fileinfo = file_get_contents($_FILES['data']['tmp_name']);
```